# haproxy container error when starting ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, haproxy, amazon-ecs

I've been trying for some time to work out what is the problem when I start the haproxy container on AWS ECS cluster. Any help to diagnose and fix the problem would be appreciated. This is the error below. I created security group rules on the linked container to allow traffic on the required ports.

```
<7>haproxy-systemd-wrapper: executing /usr/local/sbin/haproxy -p /run/haproxy.pid -db -f /usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -Ds

Usage : haproxy [-f <cfgfile|cfgdir>]* [ -vdVD ] [ -n <maxconn> ] [ -N <maxpconn> ]

    [ -p <pidfile> ] [ -m <max megs> ] [ -C <dir> ] [-- <cfgfile>*]

    -v displays version ; -vv shows known build options.

    -d enters debug mode ; -db only disables background mode.

    -dM[<byte>] poisons memory with <byte> (defaults to 0x50)

    -V enters verbose mode (disables quiet mode)

    -D goes daemon ; -C changes to <dir> before loading files.

    -q quiet mode : don't display messages

    -c check mode : only check config files and exit

    -n sets the maximum total # of connections (2000)

    -m limits the usable amount of memory (in MB)

    -N sets the default, per-proxy maximum # of connections (2000)

    -L set local peer name (default to hostname)

    -p writes pids of all children to this file

    -de disables epoll() usage even when available

    -dp disables poll() usage even when available

    -dS disables splice usage (broken on old kernels)

    -dR disables SO_REUSEPORT usage

    -dr ignores server address resolution failures

    -dV disables SSL verify on servers side

    -sf/-st [pid ]* finishes/terminates old pids.

 HA-Proxy version 1.7.10-a7dcc3b 2018/01/02

 Copyright 2000-2018 Willy Tarreau <willy@haproxy.org>

 <5>haproxy-systemd-wrapper: exit, haproxy RC=1
```

Comment: Looks like it doesn't know what `-Ds` is, as it's not an allowable flag from the output. Perhaps you meant `-dS`?

Comment: yes, I noticed that as well. only problem is that I didn't create the image, it's the docker image https://github.com/docker-library/haproxy/blob/7c772b810df3afe6884d0fb8b83720f992c3951b/1.7/Dockerfile It runs on localhost